# JavaScript isn't communicating with my HTML in WordPress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some issues with my scripts loading on WordPress. I have a few buttons (I included one in the coding section.) but whenever I click the button it says there is no function. I thought okay, that's odd, so I added some alerts and console.log statements. In my cart.js script, the `console.log()` worked and got through, but it seems my scripts for the rectangle and so on does not get loaded properly.

I tried a conventional loading of the script, but still the function seemed unable to target the HTML. Meaning, my JavaScript is hooked to some HTML buttons, but whenever the buttons are clicked I get errors about the functions not being defined.

[image]

I also tried creating all the necessary functions in the console, but that didn't work either.

What I believe to be the relevant code is under here. I included another imported script, because this worked while my other did not. I could include the HTML, but I did develop everything before I started implementing it to WordPress, and it worked fine then.
If I have failed to include something, then let me know.

```
wp_enqueue_script('cart-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cart.js', array('jquery'), '4.4.0', true);

function enqueue_product_specific_scripts() {
    if (is_product()) {
        global $product;

        if ($product instanceof WC_Product) {
            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            switch ($product_id) {
                case 18:
                    wp_enqueue_script('circle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/circle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                    break;
                case 17:
                    wp_enqueue_script('triangle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/triangle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                    break;
                case 16:
                    wp_enqueue_script('rectangle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/rectangle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_product_specific_scripts');
```

```
<button id= "createrectangle" onclick = 'createRectangle()'>Rektangel</button>
```

---

Update 1

Here is a reproducible example that shows the issue: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rq0dm92s/2/). 
*It seems that it doesn't like fabric.js in this site*.

```js
jQuery($ => {

console.log('hello, rec loaded properly');

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
const bolts = [];

// Create default rectangle on page load
createDefaultRectangle();

function createDefaultRectangle() {
    const defaultWidth = 280; // Specify the default width
    const defaultHeight = 140; // Specify the default height

    const rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        width: defaultWidth,
        height: defaultHeight,
        fill: 'lightgray',
        selectable: false,
        strokeWidth: 0.5,
        stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    });

    const boltRadius = 10; // adjust the size of the bolt holes if needed
    const boltOffset = 15; // bolt offset from rectangle borders

    const topLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const topRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + defaultWidth - boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const bottomLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + defaultHeight - boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const bottomRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + defaultWidth - boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + defaultHeight - boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });

    bolts.push(topLeftBolt);
    bolts.push(topRightBolt);
    bolts.push(bottomLeftBolt);
    bolts.push(bottomRightBolt);

    canvas.add(rectangle, topLeftBolt, topRightBolt, bottomLeftBolt, bottomRightBolt);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function createRectangle(){
    const width = parseInt(document.getElementById('x-axis').value);
    const height = parseInt(document.getElementById('y-axis').value);
    const cornerRadius = parseInt(document.getElementById('rect-radius').value);

    const rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fill: 'lightgray',
        selectable: false,
        strokeWidth: 0.5,
        stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        rx: cornerRadius,
        ry: cornerRadius
    });

    // default bolts under
    const boltRadius = 10; // adjust the size of the bolt holes if needed
    const miniumOffset = (boltRadius / 2) + 1;
    
    let boltOffset = 15; // bolt offset from rectangle borders
    if (boltOffset < miniumOffset) {
        boltOffset = miniumOffset; // update the bolt offset if its less than the min
    }

    const topLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const topRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + width - boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const bottomLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + height - boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const bottomRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + width - boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + height - boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });

    bolts.length = 0; // clear the bolts array

    bolts.push(topLeftBolt);
    bolts.push(topRightBolt);
    bolts.push(bottomLeftBolt);
    bolts.push(bottomRightBolt);

    toggleBoltNumber(); // set the number of visible bolts according to the radio button selection

    canvas.clear();
    canvas.add(rectangle, topLeftBolt, topRightBolt, bottomLeftBolt, bottomRightBolt);
    canvas.renderAll();

}

function moveBolt() {
    const boltX = parseInt(document.getElementById('bolt-x').value);
    const boltY = parseInt(document.getElementById('bolt-y').value);

    const rectangle = canvas.item(0);

    const topLeftBolt = bolts[0];
    const topRightBolt = bolts[1];
    const bottomLeftBolt = bolts[2];
    const bottomRightBolt = bolts[3];

    const boltRadius = topLeftBolt.radius;

    const rectLeft = rectangle.left + boltRadius;
    const rectTop = rectangle.top + boltRadius;
    const rectWidth = rectangle.width - 2 * boltRadius;
    const rectHeight = rectangle.height - 2 * boltRadius;

    const newTopLeftX = rectLeft + boltX;
    const newTopLeftY = rectTop + boltY;
    
    const newTopRightX = rectLeft + rectWidth - boltX;
    const newTopRightY = rectTop + boltY;

    const newBottomLeftX = rectLeft + boltX;
    const newBottomLeftY = rectTop + rectHeight - boltY;

    const newBottomRightX = rectLeft + rectWidth - boltX;
    const newBottomRightY = rectTop + rectHeight - boltY;

    topLeftBolt.set({
        left: newTopLeftX, 
        top: newTopLeftY
    });
    topRightBolt.set({
        left: newTopRightX,
        top: newTopRightY
    });
    bottomLeftBolt.set({
        left: newBottomLeftX,
        top: newBottomLeftY
    });
    bottomRightBolt.set({
        left: newBottomRightX,
        top: newBottomRightY
    });

    console.log(newTopLeftX, 'topleft');
    console.log(newTopRightX, 'topright');
    console.log(newBottomLeftX, 'bottomleft');
    console.log(newBottomRightX, 'bottomright');
    
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function shapeBolt(){

    const shapeSize = parseInt(document.getElementById('shape-size').value);

    const boltRadius = shapeSize / 2;

    bolts.forEach((bolt) => {
        bolt.set({
            radius: boltRadius,
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1
        });
    });

    canvas.renderAll();
}


const twoBoltsRadio = document.getElementById('twoBolts');
const fourBoltsRadio = document.getElementById('fourBolts');

function toggleBoltNumber(){
    const selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="boltNumber"]:checked').value;

    if (selectedValue === '2') {
        // show 2 bolts
        bolts[2].visible = false;
        bolts[3].visible = false;

    } else if(selectedValue === '4'){
        // show 4 bolts
        bolts.forEach((bolt) =>{
            bolt.visible = true;
        })
    }

    canvas.renderAll();

}

let square_MM = 0;

function squareMM() {
    const width = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x-axis').value);
    const height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y-axis').value);

    square_MM = height * width;

    document.getElementById('result').innerText = square_MM;
}

function calculatePrice(){
    const metalType = document.getElementById('metal-type').value;

    let price;
    if (metalType === "Kaldvalset" || metalType === "Varmvalsede") {
        const areaInSquareMillimeters = square_MM;
        price = areaInSquareMillimeters * 0.01;
    } else if (metalType === 'Aluminium') {
        const areaInSquareMillimeters = square_MM;
        price = areaInSquareMillimeters * 0.02;
    } else if (metalType === "Rustfritt") {
        const areaInSquareMillimeters = square_MM;
        price = areaInSquareMillimeters * 0.03;
    }

    // mva
    price = price * 1.25

    // Display the price
    document.getElementById('price').innerText = 'Price: ' + price.toFixed(2) + ' NOK';
}

});
```

```css
.kontainer{
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-left:5%;
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
        <div class = 'shape'>
            <canvas id = 'canvas' width="550" height="350"></canvas>
        </div>

        <div class = "kontainer">
            <h3>Rektangel</h3>
            <p>Angi en lengde og bredde. Eksempel 100x50mm, 80x40mm og så videre. Max er 500x300mm</p>
            <label for="x-axis">Angi høyde i mm for bredden</label>
            <input type="number" id = "x-axis" placeholder = "bredde">            
            <br>
            <label for="y-axis">Angi høyde i mm for høyden</label>
            <input type="number" id = "y-axis" placeholder = "høyde">
            <br>
            <label for="rect-radius">Hjørne radius</label>
            <input type="number" id="rect-radius" placeholder="radius">
            
            <button onclick = 'createRectangle()'>Rektangel</button>
            <div class = "kontainer">
                <h3>Bolt konfigurasjoner</h3>
                <label for="twoBolts">2 boltehull</label>
                <input type="radio" id = "twoBolts" name = "boltNumber" value = "2" onclick = "toggleBoltNumber()">
                <br>
                <label for="fourBolts">4 boltehull</label>
                <input type="radio" id="fourBolts" name="boltNumber" value = "4" checked onclick = "toggleBoltNumber()">
            

                <p><b>Angi boltstørrelse</b></p>
                <label for = "shape-size">Gi boltform i mm</label>
                <input type = "number" id = "shape-size">
                <!--<label for="bolt-radius">Gi bolt radius, i mm</label>
                <input type="number" id="bolt-radius">-->
                <br>
                <button onclick = "shapeBolt()">Form</button>

                <br>

                <label for="bolt-x">Gi hullposisjon, i mm, for bredden. (side 1)</label>
                <input type="number" id="bolt-x" placeholder="2 mm">
                <br>
                <label for="bolt-y">Gi hullposisjon, i mm, for høyden. (side 2)</label>
                <input type="number" id="bolt-y" placeholder="2 mm">
                <br>
                <button onclick = "moveBolt()">Flytt bolt</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "kontainer">
            <h4>Pris</h4>
            <select id="metal-type">
                <option value = "Kaldvalset"> Kaldvalset plate NS-EN 10130 (svart stål) </option>
                <option value = "Varmvalsede"> Varmvalsede plater S235JR (svart stål) </option>
                <option value = "Varmvalsede"> Varmvalsede plater S355J2+N (svart stål) </option>
                <option value = "Aluminium"> Aluminium 5754 (5052) NS-EN 1024 </option>
                <option value = "Rustfritt"> Rustfritt 316L syrefast (2B 0-3mm/NO 1 4-20mm) </option>
            </select>
            <button onclick= "squareMM(); calculatePrice()">Kalkuler Pris</button>
            <div>
                <br>
                <label for="result">Kvadrat mm: </label>
                <p id="result"></p>
                <label for="price">Anslått pris: </label>
                <p id="price"></p> + 25 % MVA
            </div>
       </div>
```

---

Update 2:

I changed the hook priority in add_action to `30` and I also added:

```php
function enqueue_product_specific_scripts() {
    if (is_product()) {
        global $product;
        global $post; 
        
        $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

        if ($product instanceof WC_Product) {
            $product_id = $product->get_id();
            switch ($product_id) {
                case 18:
                    wp_enqueue_script('circle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/circle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                    break;
                case 17:
                    wp_enqueue_script('triangle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/triangle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                    break;
                case 16:
                    wp_enqueue_script('rectangle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/rectangle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_product_specific_scripts', 30 );
```

Now the script is loading, but Still cannot target the HTML properly.

---

Update 3:
So the issue has been **solved**. The functions were not accessible as they were wrapped in jquery. Meaning, I needed to declare the functions so that they were accessible globaly. Example:

```
    window.squareMM = funciton(){
// here is your function
}
```

Comment: Is the script actually loaded? As in if you check devtools is it a 404 or a 200?

Comment: @JaDa nope. Not at all. I dont understand it, as when I try to load conventionally it gets throguh alright. But still it doesnt seem to target the html

Comment: Could you provide in your question the code for `rectangle.js`, please? What do you mean when you say *"it doesnt seem to target the html"*?

Comment: rectangle.js is almost 300 lines, so I figured it would be easier without it. rectangle.js draws a rectangle with fabric.js. It is hooked to a button, and when button is clicked the console tells me the functions are not defined.

Answer (score 3):

If your scripts (like *rectangle.js*) are not loaded, try the following simplified version:

```php
function enqueue_product_specific_scripts() {
    if ( is_product() ) { 
        switch ( get_the_ID() ) {
            case 18:
                wp_enqueue_script('circle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/circle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                break;
            case 17:
                wp_enqueue_script('triangle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/triangle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                break;
            case 16:
                wp_enqueue_script('rectangle-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/rectangle.js', array('jquery', 'fabric-js'), null, false);
                break;
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_product_specific_scripts', 999 );
```

Maybe this issue could be related to: 
 [How to access a function from one script in another script in JavaScript jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76900367/how-to-access-a-function-from-one-script-in-another-script-in-javascript-jquery/76900603#76900603)

---

**Update**

So your problem was directly related to my linked answer Just above.

Based on your [jsFiddle code example](https://jsfiddle.net/rq0dm92s/2/) I have been able to make it work.

The HTML and the CSS are untouched.

Here is your revisited code:

```js
// Outside the ready() event method

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var bolts = [];

function createRectangle(){
    const width = parseInt(document.getElementById('x-axis').value);
    const height = parseInt(document.getElementById('y-axis').value);
    const cornerRadius = parseInt(document.getElementById('rect-radius').value);

    const rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 50,
        top: 50,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fill: 'lightgray',
        selectable: false,
        strokeWidth: 0.5,
        stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        rx: cornerRadius,
        ry: cornerRadius
    });

    // default bolts under
    const boltRadius = 10; // adjust the size of the bolt holes if needed
    const miniumOffset = (boltRadius / 2) + 1;
    
    let boltOffset = 15; // bolt offset from rectangle borders
    if (boltOffset < miniumOffset) {
        boltOffset = miniumOffset; // update the bolt offset if its less than the min
    }

    const topLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const topRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + width - boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const bottomLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + height - boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });
    const bottomRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
        left: rectangle.left + width - boltOffset,
        top: rectangle.top + height - boltOffset,
        radius: boltRadius,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });

    bolts.length = 0; // clear the bolts array

    bolts.push(topLeftBolt);
    bolts.push(topRightBolt);
    bolts.push(bottomLeftBolt);
    bolts.push(bottomRightBolt);

    toggleBoltNumber(); // set the number of visible bolts according to the radio button selection

    canvas.clear();
    canvas.add(rectangle, topLeftBolt, topRightBolt, bottomLeftBolt, bottomRightBolt);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function toggleBoltNumber(){
    const selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="boltNumber"]:checked').value;

    if (selectedValue === '2') {
        // show 2 bolts
        bolts[2].visible = false;
        bolts[3].visible = false;

    } else if(selectedValue === '4'){
        // show 4 bolts
        bolts.forEach((bolt) =>{
            bolt.visible = true;
        })
    }

    canvas.renderAll();
}

function shapeBolt(){
    const shapeSize = parseInt(document.getElementById('shape-size').value);

    const boltRadius = shapeSize / 2;

    bolts.forEach((bolt) => {
        bolt.set({
            radius: boltRadius,
            scaleX: 1,
            scaleY: 1
        });
    });

    canvas.renderAll();
}

function moveBolt() {
    const boltX = parseInt(document.getElementById('bolt-x').value);
    const boltY = parseInt(document.getElementById('bolt-y').value);

    const rectangle = canvas.item(0);

    const topLeftBolt = bolts[0];
    const topRightBolt = bolts[1];
    const bottomLeftBolt = bolts[2];
    const bottomRightBolt = bolts[3];

    const boltRadius = topLeftBolt.radius;

    const rectLeft = rectangle.left + boltRadius;
    const rectTop = rectangle.top + boltRadius;
    const rectWidth = rectangle.width - 2 * boltRadius;
    const rectHeight = rectangle.height - 2 * boltRadius;

    const newTopLeftX = rectLeft + boltX;
    const newTopLeftY = rectTop + boltY;
    
    const newTopRightX = rectLeft + rectWidth - boltX;
    const newTopRightY = rectTop + boltY;

    const newBottomLeftX = rectLeft + boltX;
    const newBottomLeftY = rectTop + rectHeight - boltY;

    const newBottomRightX = rectLeft + rectWidth - boltX;
    const newBottomRightY = rectTop + rectHeight - boltY;

    topLeftBolt.set({
        left: newTopLeftX, 
        top: newTopLeftY
    });
    topRightBolt.set({
        left: newTopRightX,
        top: newTopRightY
    });
    bottomLeftBolt.set({
        left: newBottomLeftX,
        top: newBottomLeftY
    });
    bottomRightBolt.set({
        left: newBottomRightX,
        top: newBottomRightY
    });

    console.log(newTopLeftX, 'topleft');
    console.log(newTopRightX, 'topright');
    console.log(newBottomLeftX, 'bottomleft');
    console.log(newBottomRightX, 'bottomright');
    
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function squareMM() {
    const width = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x-axis').value);
    const height = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y-axis').value);

    square_MM = height * width;

    document.getElementById('result').innerText = square_MM;
}

function calculatePrice(){
    const metalType = document.getElementById('metal-type').value;

    let price;
    if (metalType === "Kaldvalset" || metalType === "Varmvalsede") {
        const areaInSquareMillimeters = square_MM;
        price = areaInSquareMillimeters * 0.01;
    } else if (metalType === 'Aluminium') {
        const areaInSquareMillimeters = square_MM;
        price = areaInSquareMillimeters * 0.02;
    } else if (metalType === "Rustfritt") {
        const areaInSquareMillimeters = square_MM;
        price = areaInSquareMillimeters * 0.03;
    }

    // mva
    price = price * 1.25

    // Display the price
    document.getElementById('price').innerText = 'Price: ' + price.toFixed(2) + ' NOK';
}


// Inside the ready() event method

jQuery($ => {
    console.log('hello, rec loaded properly');

    // Create default rectangle on page load
    createDefaultRectangle();

    function createDefaultRectangle() {
        const defaultWidth = 280; // Specify the default width
        const defaultHeight = 140; // Specify the default height

        const rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 50,
            top: 50,
            width: defaultWidth,
            height: defaultHeight,
            fill: 'lightgray',
            selectable: false,
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
            stroke: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        });

        const boltRadius = 10; // adjust the size of the bolt holes if needed
        const boltOffset = 15; // bolt offset from rectangle borders

        const topLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
            left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
            top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
            radius: boltRadius,
            fill: 'white',
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            selectable: false
        });
        const topRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
            left: rectangle.left + defaultWidth - boltOffset,
            top: rectangle.top + boltOffset,
            radius: boltRadius,
            fill: 'white',
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            selectable: false
        });
        const bottomLeftBolt = new fabric.Circle({
            left: rectangle.left + boltOffset,
            top: rectangle.top + defaultHeight - boltOffset,
            radius: boltRadius,
            fill: 'white',
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            selectable: false
        });
        const bottomRightBolt = new fabric.Circle({
            left: rectangle.left + defaultWidth - boltOffset,
            top: rectangle.top + defaultHeight - boltOffset,
            radius: boltRadius,
            fill: 'white',
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            selectable: false
        });

        bolts.push(topLeftBolt);
        bolts.push(topRightBolt);
        bolts.push(bottomLeftBolt);
        bolts.push(bottomRightBolt);

        canvas.add(rectangle, topLeftBolt, topRightBolt, bottomLeftBolt, bottomRightBolt);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }

    const twoBoltsRadio = document.getElementById('twoBolts');
    const fourBoltsRadio = document.getElementById('fourBolts');
    let square_MM = 0;
});
```

```css
.kontainer{
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-left:5%;
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'shape'>
    <canvas id = 'canvas' width="550" height="350"></canvas>
</div>

<div class = "kontainer">
    <h3>Rektangel</h3>
    <p>Angi en lengde og bredde. Eksempel 100x50mm, 80x40mm og så videre. Max er 500x300mm</p>
    <label for="x-axis">Angi høyde i mm for bredden</label>
    <input type="number" id = "x-axis" placeholder = "bredde">            
    <br>
    <label for="y-axis">Angi høyde i mm for høyden</label>
    <input type="number" id = "y-axis" placeholder = "høyde">
    <br>
    <label for="rect-radius">Hjørne radius</label>
    <input type="number" id="rect-radius" placeholder="radius">
    
    <button onclick = 'createRectangle()'>Rektangel</button>
    <div class = "kontainer">
        <h3>Bolt konfigurasjoner</h3>
        <label for="twoBolts">2 boltehull</label>
        <input type="radio" id = "twoBolts" name = "boltNumber" value = "2" onclick = "toggleBoltNumber()">
        <br>
        <label for="fourBolts">4 boltehull</label>
        <input type="radio" id="fourBolts" name="boltNumber" value = "4" checked onclick = "toggleBoltNumber()">
    

        <p><b>Angi boltstørrelse</b></p>
        <label for = "shape-size">Gi boltform i mm</label>
        <input type = "number" id = "shape-size">
        <!--<label for="bolt-radius">Gi bolt radius, i mm</label>
        <input type="number" id="bolt-radius">-->
        <br>
        <button onclick = "shapeBolt()">Form</button>

        <br>

        <label for="bolt-x">Gi hullposisjon, i mm, for bredden. (side 1)</label>
        <input type="number" id="bolt-x" placeholder="2 mm">
        <br>
        <label for="bolt-y">Gi hullposisjon, i mm, for høyden. (side 2)</label>
        <input type="number" id="bolt-y" placeholder="2 mm">
        <br>
        <button onclick = "moveBolt()">Flytt bolt</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "kontainer">
    <h4>Pris</h4>
    <select id="metal-type">
        <option value = "Kaldvalset"> Kaldvalset plate NS-EN 10130 (svart stål) </option>
        <option value = "Varmvalsede"> Varmvalsede plater S235JR (svart stål) </option>
        <option value = "Varmvalsede"> Varmvalsede plater S355J2+N (svart stål) </option>
        <option value = "Aluminium"> Aluminium 5754 (5052) NS-EN 1024 </option>
        <option value = "Rustfritt"> Rustfritt 316L syrefast (2B 0-3mm/NO 1 4-20mm) </option>
    </select>
    <button onclick= "squareMM(); calculatePrice()">Kalkuler Pris</button>
    <div>
        <br>
        <label for="result">Kvadrat mm: </label>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <label for="price">Anslått pris: </label>
        <p id="price"></p> + 25 % MVA
    </div>
   </div>
```

This worked perfectly for me, allowing to get the price.

Comment: I will try this now and bcome back to you

Comment: So this loads the script yes, but it still has trouble communicating with my html. I'm adding what is expected to happend to OP

Comment: I included a screenshot too

Comment: Sadly this didn't change the situaion at all

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, as I have written everything for it to work in worpdress. Do I use the resource above and copy paste my parts of the script? Sorry I am pretty new to this way of working

Comment: I tried adding it now. jsfiddle struggled with recognising the fabric.js but I assure you that this has not been an issue locally

Comment: Yeah it works in this context, but it doesnt seem to load properly in WordPress. Sorry if I was unclear about that being a requirement. The script is loaded, it's there with a 200, but when I click any button the console logs errors that the related script is not defined